# SwiftUI Alert and Accessibility with Voiceover

Tags: swiftui, accessibility, alert, voiceover

Currently, when an alert appears, voiceover focuses on the alert's title. However, the title and the message are two independent elements, causing the voiceover user to have to swipe in order to hear the message, and then swipe again to get to the button(s).

Is there a way to make the title and the message of an alert a single element so that it is read together? Just trying to make the user experience a bit nicer for our assistive users.

Here's the code for the alert:

```
.alert(
    Text("My Title"),
    isPresented: $showAlert,
    actions: {
    Button("Cancel", role: .cancel) { }

    Button("Delete", role: .destructive) {
        myFunc()
    }
},
message: {
    Text("My message")
})
```